# sub-millisecond time measurement in Ruby

Tags: ruby, time, benchmarking, timing, metrics

I'm running Ruby 2.2 in Rubymine 8.0.3

My machine is running Windows 7 Pro with an Intel core i7-4710MQ

I've been able to achieve ~411 ns precision with C++, Java, Python and JS on this machine, but can't seem to find a way to attain this performance in Ruby, as the built in Time library is good for ms only.

I can program my tests to tolerate this reduced precision, but is it possible to incorporate the windows QPC API for improved evaluation of execution time?

My test code for determining clock tick precision is below:

```
numTimes = 10000
times = Array.new(numTimes)

(0...(numTimes)).each do |i|
  times[i] = Time.new
end

durations = []
(0...(numTimes - 1)).each do |i|
  durations[i] = times[i+1] - times[i]
end

# Output duration only if the clock ticked over    
durations.each do |duration|
  if duration != 0
    p duration.to_s + ','
  end
end
```

The below code incorporates the QPC as found [here](http://blade.nagaokaut.ac.jp/cgi-bin/scat.rb/ruby/ruby-talk/165319)

```
require "Win32API"

QueryPerformanceCounter = Win32API.new("kernel32",
                                       "QueryPerformanceCounter", 'P', 'I')
QueryPerformanceFrequency = Win32API.new("kernel32",
                                         "QueryPerformanceFrequency", 'P', 'I')

def get_ticks
  tick = ' ' * 8
  get_ticks = QueryPerformanceCounter.call(tick)
  tick.unpack('q')[0]
end

def get_freq
  freq = ' ' * 8
  get_freq =  QueryPerformanceFrequency.call(freq)
  freq.unpack('q')[0]
end

def get_time_diff(a, b)
  # This function takes two QPC ticks
  (b - a).abs.to_f / (get_freq)
end

numTimes = 10000
times = Array.new(numTimes)

(0...(numTimes)).each do |i|
  times[i] = get_ticks
end

durations = []
(0...(numTimes - 1)).each do |i|
  durations[i] = get_time_diff(times[i+1], times[i])
end

durations.each do |duration|
    p (duration * 1000000000).to_s + ','
end
```

This code returns durations between ticks of ~22-75 microseconds on my machine

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this code? Benchmarking? Also, I think you have a syntax error. `if duration u!= 0`

Comment: good catch, must have slipped in while I was editing the submission. I'm using this timing code to validate the timer's performance. I'll be using the timer to measure durations of matrix initialization and multiplication for various NxN sizes.

Comment: Have you considered using [Benchmark](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/benchmark/rdoc/Benchmark.html)?

Answer (score 2):

You can get higher precision by using [`Process::clock_gettime`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Process.html#method-c-clock_gettime):

> Returns a time returned by POSIX `clock_gettime()` function.

Here's an example with `Time.now`

```
times = Array.new(1000) { Time.now }
durations = times.each_cons(2).map { |a, b| b - a }

durations.sort.group_by(&:itself).each do |time, elements|
  printf("%5d ns x %d\n", time * 1_000_000_000, elements.count)
end
```

Output:

```
    0 ns x 686
 1000 ns x 296
 2000 ns x 12
 3000 ns x 2
12000 ns x 2
18000 ns x 1
```

And here's the same example with `Process.clock_gettime`:

```
times = Array.new(1000) { Process.clock_gettime(Process::CLOCK_MONOTONIC) }
```

Output:

```
  163 ns x 1
  164 ns x 1
  164 ns x 9
  165 ns x 6
  165 ns x 22
  166 ns x 39
  166 ns x 174
  167 ns x 13
  167 ns x 129
  168 ns x 95
  168 ns x 32
  169 ns x 203
  169 ns x 141
  170 ns x 23
  170 ns x 37
  171 ns x 30
  171 ns x 3
  172 ns x 24
  172 ns x 10
  174 ns x 1
  175 ns x 2
  180 ns x 1
  194 ns x 1
  273 ns x 1
 2565 ns x 1
```

And here's a quick side-by-side comparison:

```
array = Array.new(12) { [Time.now, Process.clock_gettime(Process::CLOCK_MONOTONIC)] }

array.shift(2)                # first elements are always inaccuate
base_t, base_p = array.first  # baseline

printf("%-11.11s %-11.11s\n", 'Time.now', 'Process.clock_gettime')
array.each do |t, p|
  printf("%.9f %.9f\n", t - base_t, p - base_p)
end
```

Output:

```
Time.now    Process.clo
0.000000000 0.000000000
0.000000000 0.000000495
0.000001000 0.000000985
0.000001000 0.000001472
0.000002000 0.000001960
0.000002000 0.000002448
0.000003000 0.000002937
0.000003000 0.000003425
0.000004000 0.000003914
0.000004000 0.000004403
```

This is Ruby 2.3 on OS X running on an Intel Core i7, not sure about Windows.

To avoid precision loss due to floating point conversion, you can specify another unit, e.g.:

```
Process.clock_gettime(Process::CLOCK_MONOTONIC, :nanosecond)
#=> 191519383463873
```

Comment: `Process.clock_gettime(Process::CLOCK_MONOTONIC)` returns a Float number of seconds which doesn't quite have enough precision for truly accurate nanoseconds.  To be precise, use `Process.clock_gettime(Process::CLOCK_MONOTONIC, :nanosecond)` which will return a Fixnum of nanoseconds.

Comment: @Schwern are you sure? I don't see a precision loss due to floats.

Comment: Maybe. The docs state: `The underlying function, ::clock_gettime(), returns a number of nanoseconds. Float object (IEEE 754 double) is not enough to represent the return value for CLOCK_REALTIME. If the exact nanoseconds value is required, use :nanoseconds as the unit.` Maybe `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` can get away with it, but I wouldn't risk it. [Testing on my machine shows it's right on the edge of nanosecond precision](https://gist.github.com/schwern/32b809c1eec1487d5506), but who knows for another machine?

Answer (score 1):

[`Time#nsec`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Time.html#method-i-nsec):

```
numTimes = 10000
times = Array.new(numTimes)

(0...(numTimes)).each do |i|
  # nsec              ⇓⇓⇓⇓
  times[i] = Time.new.nsec
end

durations = (0...(numTimes - 1)).inject([]) do |memo, i|
  memo << times[i+1] - times[i]
end

puts durations.reject(&:zero?).join $/
```

Comment: what results are you getting on your machine with this code? Mine is returning 1ms for all non-zero durations

Comment: MacOS? I get smth like `[253, 430, 286, ...]`.

Comment: OK so this behaviour I'm seeing with Time.new is certainly OS related then, I get 1000000 for every value (1 ms). I couldn't find anything better than invoking QPC in the way I did above for Windows.

Comment: I have no clue what `QPC` stands for. You have asked about nanoseconds and I provided an answer on how to get nanosecond precision in ruby. That’s it.

Comment: it stands for Query Performance Counter, the documentation may be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn553408(v=vs.85).aspx) Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

[Ruby Time objects](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Time.html) store the number of nanoseconds since the epoch.

> Since Ruby 1.9.2, Time implementation uses a signed 63 bit integer, Bignum or Rational. The integer is a number of nanoseconds since the Epoch which can represent 1823-11-12 to 2116-02-20.

You can access the nanosecond part most accurately with `Time#nsec`.

```
$ ruby -e 't1 = Time.now; puts t1.to_f; puts t1.nsec'
1457079791.351686
351686000
```

As you can see, on my OS X machine it's only precise down to the microsecond.  This could be because OS X lacks `clock_gettime()`.

Comment: On _robust_ operating system, e.g. linux, the result is OK:  `Time.now.nsec
#⇒ 526952060`.

Comment: Time has sub-nanosecond precision when using Bignum or Rational.

Comment: Schwern, I understand that the operation of these timing functions can vary quite a bit based on what the underlying OS supports. I used an array of durations to capture recorded times as quickly as possible, to discover the resolution of the timer by looking at the average duration between measurements

Comment: @mudasobwa Easy on the OS hubris, please. [OS X most definitely has nanosecond time](https://gist.github.com/schwern/1a4482bfcd5feee0812c), just not `clock_gettime()`. Recent versions of ruby do use `mach_absolute_time()`, but I'm not seeing the precision it should.